# Как рассчитать значение тейкпрофита или стоплосса однократно при в ходе в сделку и сохранять его до выхода из нее PINE SCRIPT

Tags: pinescript

Вот участок кода, s1 значение моего тейкпрофита, которое я хочу посчитать при входе в сделку и сохранять его до выхода из сделки, что не так?

```
s1 = strategy.position_avg_price - atr[2] * atrMultiplierLower[2]
varip tps1 = float(0.0)
if strategy.position_size != strategy.position_size[1] 
    tps1 := s1
else
    tps1 := tps1[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s1 = strategy.position_avg_price - nz(atr[2]) * nz(atrMultiplierLower[2])
varip tps1 = float(0.0)
if strategy.position_size != nz(strategy.position_size[1])
    tps1 := s1
else
    tps1 := nz(tps1[1])
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]